# URL com palavras em português

Tags: novo-recurso, status-recusado, tradução

Olhando um link no site, é assim:

```
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer
```

Não seria mais correto, ou no mínimo mais fácil de achar para quem fala português, se fosse assim:

```
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/perguntas/como-responder
```

Comment: Eu discordo. Acho mais vantagem manter a uniformidade entre o sistema de todos os sites. Sea alguém que não fale português (o pessoal da SE, por exemplo) vier aqui, seria legal ele poder entender onde está. Outro motivo são os aplicativos ou userscripts que operam nos sites da rede. Devem funciona agnósticos ao site, e ai entra a url uniforme.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Faz sentido o que você disse, mas nada impede que haja outras rotas, em português, apontando para as mesmas páginas.

Comment: @bfavaretto Não havia pensado nisso. Sendo assim, não vejo problemas.

Comment: Eu já havia levantado esta questão aqui, e na época sugeri como redirecionamento: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/628/ ... Pra falar a verdade, entendo até como duplicata, visto que "help" foi um exemplo.

Comment: @Bacco na verdade eu preferiria fechar a sua anterior, já que esta aqui está mais ampla (mais "canonica") enquanto que o help é foi um exemplo.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal tudo bem que estou "advogando em causa própria", mas naquela fiz um titulo que você olhando, sabe exatamente do que se trata. Esta aqui você só sabe por ter lido o conteúdo. Não vou mexer naquela agora, pra nao criar uma disputa boba, mas seria só evidenciar no corpo do texto que o help é exemplo. Quanto a fechar, eu nao votei em nenhuma, por nao haver resposta em nenhuma. Não me incomodo em remover, se for o caso, mas pra mim as duas "empatam".

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal -- também estou nem aí qual das duas "ganham" em ser a pergunta apropriada. Infelizmente não achei a do Bacco, e por isso perguntei outra dessa forma.

Comment: @Bacco Editei seu título, espero não causar disputa boba. Depois vemos qual fechar.

Comment: E agora com o editação do bfavaretto, é mais claro que nunca que dupliquei a pergunta :P Pode fechando essa aqui gente! :D

Comment: @Bacco Retirei o voto lá e votei aqui. Não faz muita diferença qual é fechada na verdade. São bem parecidas. E agora com a edição, a outra voltou para a home e o assunto não vai morrer com o fechamento aqui.

Comment: @bfavaretto há como você transformar aquela minha em wiki da comunidade? Assim ficaria mais legal, e os detalhes a mais desta poderiam ser acrescidos lá, de maneira "neutra".

Comment: @Bacco A comunidade já fechou esta. Nem acho necessário botar a outra como CW, você quer isso mesmo?

Comment: @bfavaretto acho justo, pois eu ja havia "abandonado" a idéia, e agora é um misto das idéias da comunidade. Se puder fazer isto, agradeço.

Comment: Ok @Bacco, feito.